# How can I pair device to Android Studio Bumblebee using Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, pairing, android-studio-bumblebee

I want to debug my app via the last release of Android Studio Bumblebee using Wi-Fi (without wire connecting). How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure that your device has **Android version 11**+. Android Studio Bumblebee supports the wireless debugging feature on **Android 11** and higher devices.

Secondly, make sure that you use the last release of Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio

Then

1. Open available devices menu
2. Choose `Pair devices Using Wi-Fi` and you can see QR-code which you can scan via your phone
3. Go to device settings: `System -> Developer options -> Wireless debugging -> Pair device with QR code`
4. Scan QR code using the device camera. Wait several seconds. Your device must be paired

If `developer options` isn't available on your device settings then activate it first, see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

1.[image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Comment: Nuance: at the time of writing, this doesn't work for me when *tethering to the device* that I want to connect via Android Studio.  In my case, I wanted to debug wirelessly whilst connecting the Android device to external USB hardware.